# Как вставить пробел через 4 символа?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть вот такой текст `(string) 4929228339917848`. Можно ли вставлять пробел через каждые 4 символа? Т.е: `4929 2283 3991 7848`.

Comment: Это чей номер карточки? :)

Comment: @Athari, Бедного нефтяного магната с Соединённых Штатов Пиндосии. ТС админку для банковского троя пишет же :)

Comment: @TheDoctor , это вообще случайно сгенерированный :)

Comment: Конечно, кто ж выложит реальный номер кредитки магната? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$str = "1234123412341234";
echo chunk_split($str, 4, ' ');
```

Comment: Неплохой финт ушами, но в данном случае будет лишний пробел после последнего блока.
Надо заюзать `trim`.

Comment: @TheDoctor, ну, лишний пробел не всегда смертелен :)

Comment: Да ну?
Лишняя запятая тоже погоды не сделает, думал чувак, пишущий "Казнить, нельзя помиловать"...

Comment: @TheDoctor если бы он поставил лишний пробел, пробел бы не являлся основанием для казни :)

Comment: Угу, просто работодатель на подобный случай запасся вазелином. Уже лучше казнь :)